# How can I populate a drop-down on the front-end using Sprout Forms?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have a contact form where I can choose the current state (U.S states).
I have the field created in Sprout forms as "state" and is populated with all 50 states.

I would like to use "custom" html and loop through the values of that field. I just can't figure out how to get to it.

I know I can output the whole field/element using:

```
{{ craft.sproutForms.displayField('contact.state') }}
```

But that outputs a whole html element. I only want the options so I can loop over them like this:

```
....
<select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    {% set states = form.getField('contact.state') %}
        {% for option in states %}
            <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
....
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Sprout Forms 2.0, this has become a lot easier.  Hopefully I can win that last answer away from myself!

#### A few options

First, Sprout Forms 2.0 adds multiple new override options so you may be able to address this problem in a different way now to that will get away from needing to handle this in Custom HTML.  Things to consider:

- [Template Overrides](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/template-overrides) - If you were using custom HTML because the default templates we're not the right HTML format for your needs, you can now easily override those default templates on a per-form basis.
- [Rendering Options](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/rendering-options) - If specific attributes of the field such as the ID or Class did not meet your needs, you could potentially dynamically override them while still using a tag like `displayForm()` or `displayField()`
- [Front-end Field API](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/customization/custom-front-end-fields) - You could create a custom plugin that adds front-end field support for a custom State Dropdown field.

#### Custom HTML

If you still feel custom HTML is the best fit for you, there is now a `SproutForms_FormModel::getField()` method and `craft.sproutForms.getEntry` tag to help manage retained values and error states.  Here is a generic example.  A more complete examples of all Standard front-end field types can be found in the docs [Custom HTML Forms and Example Fields](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/custom-html#example-code-to-manually-manage-all-default-fields-in-your-templates)

```
{# Get our Form data #}
{% set form = craft.sproutForms.form('formHandle') %}

{# Get our Form Entry data to manage error states and re-populating field values #}
{% set submittedEntry = craft.sproutForms.getEntry(form) %}

{# Get our Field Model #}
{% set dropdownField = form.getField('dropdown') %}

{# We use the Twig attribute tag to dynamically access our 
     field value on the submitted Form Entry #}
{% set submittedDropdownValue = attribute(submittedEntry, dropdownField.handle) %}

{% if dropdownField is defined %}

  {{ dropdownField.name }}

  <select name="fields[{{ dropdownField.handle }}]">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    {% for option in dropdownField.settings.options %}

      {% set defaultValue = option.default ? option.value : null %}
      {% set selectedDropdownValue = submittedDropdownValue != '' ? submittedDropdownValue : defaultValue %}

      <option value="{{ option.value }}" {% if selectedDropdownValue == option.value %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}</option>

    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  {% if submittedEntry is defined %}

    {# Assumes you have an errorList macro #}
    {{ errorList(submittedEntry.getErrors(dropdownField.handle)) }}

  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Awesome! - Great work Ben.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on a better way to handle this in future versions of Sprout Forms. (Currently Sprout Forms v1.1.0).

Right now, your options are:

1. Write a custom plugin to make this easier for yourself
2. Access the info your looking for in a fairly verbose way using the `craft.sproutForms.form` tag

Here's a rough example of how you can get access to the FieldModel of a dropdown field.  It involves retrieving the whole SproutForms_FormModel, looping through the tabs and testing for the field you wish to access:

```
{% set dropdownField = null %}
{% set form = craft.sproutForms.form('contact') %}

{% for tab in form.getFieldLayout().getTabs() %}

    {% set fields = tab.getFields() %}

    {% for field in fields %} 

        {% set required = field.required %}
        {% set tabId = field.tabId %}

        {% set field = field.getField() %}

        {% if field.handle == 'dropdownFieldHandle' %}
            {% setdropdownField = field %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{% if dropdownField is defined %}
    <select name="fields[{{ dropdownField.handle }}]">
        {% for option in dropdownField.settings.options %}
            <option value="{{ option.value }}">{{ option.label }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endif %}
```

I've made a note to update this post when we get something easier to use in place.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I was going to go with the example you provided but thought for sure I was making it a lot harder. I've been known to miss the obvious. :)

Comment: We agree it's obvious that this should be easier!